# Pycharm shortcut analogous to vims 'Shift+h/m/l' and 'z + t/./b'

Tags: navigation, editor, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a existing shortcut for below functionalities, or anyway to configure it. Not able to find the exact name to configure this. The shortcuts are given as per vim.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + (<kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>m</kbd>  or <kbd>l</kbd>)  : move the cursor to top, middle, bottom of screen(viewport)
- <kbd>z</kbd> + (<kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>b</kbd>) : puts the current line to the top/center/bottom of screen (more info here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110251/17265)

Answer (score 0):

When you type "scroll" into the search bar of the PyCharm settings, you get some options that might be of interest (please ignore the german keybindings):

[image: pycharm setting]

In the `Editor Actions` tab the `Scroll to Center` option scrolls the document to center on the cursor. I didn't try the other options for now, but I believe they behave alike.

Similarly, you can search for "caret" and get a lot of options:

[image: pycharm settings 2]

`Move Caret to Page Top/Bottom` should be what you are searching for. Sadly, I cannot find a center option for this right now.